# Heroku differentiate between production and staging app

Tags: git, heroku, playframework, synchronization, playframework-2.0

I'm creating a Play 2.1.3 web app and I have setup two environments in Heroku, one for production and one for staging.

What is the easiest way to differentiate between the two environments? For instance I don't want the search robots to index my staging app so I want to add a `robots.txt` for staging but then it will also be added for production when pushing the repo.

Should I have two local (`app-prod` and `app-staging`) Play applications with separate git repos on my computer? Then I will have to keep the two applications in sync. After verifying that the staging app on Heroku works successfully I would have to sync those changes with my production app locally on my computer (how do I do that with Git?) and then push those changes to the production app on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a route called robots.txt that either returns a 404 or the actual asset.  It could look at application.conf which in turn would read from environment variables that you would set for your different environments to modify app behavior.

Edit:

I should have explained my solution better.  You can create a controller to have some minor logic.  This is where the logic for returning a 404 or the actual robots.txt file should be given.

```
package controllers

import java.io.File
import play.api.mvc._

object Robots {

  def get = Action {
    Ok.sendFile(
      content = new File("/path/to/your/robots.txt"),
      fileName = _ => "robots.txt"
    )
  }
}
```

You can find the documentation on serving files here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaStream

And then the routes file would just have

```
GET /robots.txt   controllers.Robots.get
```

This would have higher priority than the assets controller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried what you suggested. `#{if Play.mode.isTest()}
GET  /robots.txt     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
#{/if}
#{else}
GET  /robots.txt     404
#{/else}` but I get a compilation error on the 404 line `"Controller method call expected"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Play but for my applications I use a basic authentication prompt on them  for staging so I know that nothing can be seen whilst I'm working on it or indexed at all.

If you want to use a more traditional git flow your are best with having two Heroku applications and deploy to them from a single git repo using corresponding branches - when you connect your repo to Heroku then name the remotes something like `production` and `staging` so it's easier to distinguish when you push. (you would probably be used to see `git push heroku master` up to this point)

eg

```
git remote add production <git url of production heroku app>
git remote add staging <git url of staging heroku app>
```

then your deployment process becomes;

- `git push staging staging:master` - deploy local staging branch to the `staging` remotes master branch
- verify on staging Heroku app
- `git checkout master` - switch to local master branch
- `git merge staging` - merge staging into local master
- `git push production master` - deploy local master to the `production` remote

Heroku have also introduced a new feature recently called Pipelines which sounds like it might be of also be a fit here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-pipelines.